# Don't show second crossover until price move 1% away from 1st crossover

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Crossover signal shows everytime when condition is true. I want it show less frequent. For example, second crossover signal only appears when price moves 1% away from first crossover, then 3rd crossover only appears when price moves 1% away from second crossover...

```
ema50 = ta.ema(close,50)
ema200 = ta.ema(close,200)

uptrend = ema50>ema200
downtrend = ema200>ema50

plot(ema50, color = uptrend?color.green:downtrend?color.red:na)
plot(ema200, color = uptrend?color.green:downtrend?color.red:na)

long = ta.crossover(close, ema50)

plotchar(uptrend?long:na, "Long", "▲", location.belowbar, color = color.green, text = "Long",size = size.tiny)
```

[signal shows too many](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1t70.png)

Please help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set a variable with the close price of you last signal and add a condition to check if it's 1% away from it, like this:

```
ema50 = ta.ema(close,50)
ema200 = ta.ema(close,200)

uptrend = ema50>ema200
downtrend = ema200>ema50

plot(ema50, color = uptrend?color.green:downtrend?color.red:na)
plot(ema200, color = uptrend?color.green:downtrend?color.red:na)

crossover_threshold = 0.01

var last_crossover_price = na

long = ta.crossover(close, ema50)

if long
    if na(last_crossover_price)
        plotchar(true, "Long", "▲", location.belowbar, color = color.green, text = "Long",size = size.tiny)
        last_crossover_price := close
    else if abs(close - last_crossover_price) / last_crossover_price >= crossover_threshold
        plotchar(true, "Long", "▲", location.belowbar, color = color.green, text = "Long",size = size.tiny)
        last_crossover_price := close

plotchar(uptrend?long:na, "Long", "▲", location.belowbar, color = color.green, text = "Long",size = size.tiny)
```

You can do the same for the the short sigal.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, since plotchar() cannot be used in local scope, the code should be like this, `var float last_crossover_price = na
bool long_entry_plot = false

long = ta.crossover(close, ema50)

if long
    if na(last_crossover_price)
        last_crossover_price := close
    else if math.abs(close - last_crossover_price) / last_crossover_price >= crossover_threshold
        long_entry_plot:=true
        last_crossover_price := close`